# PDOException with message SQLSTATE[42000]: 1064. Occurs when variable passed instead of string

Tags: php, mysql, variables

My code generates a fatal error when I replace strings in the code with variables equivalent to those strings.

I am trying to generate a list of Symbols of tree species that have broad and opposite leaves.  I do this just fine with a PDO prepared statement:

```
$stmt=$conn->prepare('SELECT Symbol FROM Leaf WHERE Type = ? AND BroadArrangement = ? ');
$stmt->execute(array('B' , 'O'));
$i=0;

    while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) : ?>

    <li><a href="#"><?php print_r($result['Symbol']); ?> </a></li>
    <?php $i++;
      endwhile;
```

The fatal error (see below), arises when I replace the query and the parameters to bind with variables:

```
$q="'SELECT Symbol FROM Leaf WHERE Type = ? AND BroadArrangement = ? '";
$b= " 'B','O' ";

$stmt=$conn->prepare($q);
$stmt->execute(array($b));
$i=0;
    while ($result = $stmt->fetch()) : ?>
    <li><a href="#"><?php print_r($result['Symbol']); ?> </a></li>
    <?php $i++;
         endwhile;
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''SELECT Symbol
>   FROM Leaf WHERE Type = ? AND BroadArrangement = ? '' at line 1' in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Tree_ID_Website/Compare/practice_compare.php:253
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Tree_ID_Website/Compare/practice_compare.php(253):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Tree_ID_Website/Compare/practice_compare.php
>   on line 253

I have a feeling I'm missing something simple, but I don't know what.  When I print or echo the variables, $q and $b, they are identical to the strings passed in the section of code that works properly.  Is is an issue with the scope of variables?  Or do I need to slightly modify the variables?  I tried back quotes with no luck.

From other posts this error often seems to arise when the query contains reserved keywords.  But mine does not and I'm confused.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for the quick response and suggestion.  I cleaned up the code and made it more logical so $b was an array, however the same issue remained.

Comment: See my answer below. The first error was due to extra quotes on `$q`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. First is that when building your statement in `$q` you have it quoted first in single then in double quotes. It needs to be quoted just once as a plain PHP string:

```
// Quoted with just one set of quotes
$q="SELECT Symbol FROM Leaf WHERE Type = ? AND BroadArrangement = ?";
```

Then your array of parameters must be an array where each param is one array element:

```
// Each param is an array element
$b = array('B', 0);
```

Then you can prepare and execute, passing `$b` as the parameter to `execute()`:

```
// Based on your error it looks like you have PDO configured to throw exceptions
// so use a try/catch block.
try {
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($q);
  $stmt->execute($b);
}
catch (PDOException $err) {
  // Oops error
  echo $err->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks much.  Fixing the quotes in $q and making $b an array solved the problem.  I still have much to learn as far as syntax goes.  Thanks for taking the time to help with this little issue.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work as you expect it to:

```
$b= " 'B','O' ";

$c = array($b);
```

Now `$c` will be an array that contains one element, the string `'B','O'`.

If you really have a comma separated string and what to convert it to an array, you need:

```
$c = explode(',' $b);
```

or in your case:

```
$stmt->execute( explode(',' $b) );
```

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on the answer.  Now I understand why I can't pass a single string like I did into an array and expect multiple values.  cheers.